# Export custom tags from HP Fortify SSC

Tags: fortify

I'm using HP Fortify SSC to audit security issues in a project.

In order to estimate the time needed to fix the issues, I've added a custom tag "estimate" which we fill in for each issue.

Now I would like to export a list of issues, with their "estimate" value, so that I can do some maths with the values.

How can I do this? I've tried a handful of report types, but they all seem to munge the data too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSC reports are BIRT reports that can be created/edited using the BIRT editor in Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/birt/).  If there is a shipped report that you like and just want to add the extra tag to, you can download the report template from the Reports->Report Definitions area in SSC.

EDIT 1:
Once you have the Report Definition you want to modify, open Eclipse and create a new project.  Import the report and open it.  Under `Data Sources`, open the data source and click `Manage Drivers`.  Add the JTDS driver that you added to the SSC WAR when configuring it.  Select the JTDS driver as the `Driver Class` and then specify the same `Database URL`, `User Name` and `Password` that you did in the WAR.  Then click `Test Connection...` to ensure that you can connect to the server.

It appears that SSC 4.10 uses BIRT version `2.6.2.r262_v20110120`.  I don't know if newer report versions will work, but you can always try.

EDIT 2:
If you look at the `About BIRT Reports in Software Security Center` section in the `HP Fortify SSC User Guide`, it gives a lot of information about setting up BIRT and creating/modifying the shipped reports.

Comment: Looks very promising, and I've spent the last day learning how to use BIRT. Now, to use it with SSC, what do I tell BIRT/Eclipse to use as a data source?